# Crear usuario invitado y usuario dueño de perfil en Django

Tags: django

Quiero tener la opción de generar dos tipos de usuario con Django. Uno como dueño del perfil y otro como invitado a poder ver el perfil y hacer CRUD, pero limitado a otras funciones que solamente el dueño del perfil puede hacer. Además, el invitado solo puede acceder al perfil del dueño del perfil mediante aprobación de acceso o por invitación.

Comment: Por favor, edita la pregunta para limitarla a un problema específico con suficiente detalle para identificar una respuesta adecuada.

Answer (score 0):

Pero django ya te da esa opción al momento de crear super usuario, solo agregas en el admin a usuarios y limitas las funciones que cada uno tendrá.